# arcgis geodatabase replica between different versions

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, replication

We have 2 geodatabase corresponding to 2 systems. There is a replica between these 2 geodatabase all use version 10. Recently there is a version upgrade in the parent geodatabase.
It will be upgraded to version 10.2.2 (the child veision will remain version 10). I want to confirm can I create a replica between version 10 and version 10.2.2. Is there any potential danger?

We have a scheduler to synchronize changes of the 2 geodatabase use the replica now. with the upgrade of the parent geodatabase, will the replica still work?

Comment: What is being upgraded to 10.2.2? Is the SDE version changing or the replica? What type of replica - check-out, two way?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the quick reply. it is the ArcGIS version upgraded to 10.2. It is a one-way replica.

Comment: ArcMap 10.2 can worth with a version 10 geodatabase - as far as ArcMap cares it's just another file/personal geodatabase! I wouldn't upgrade the replica database to 10.2 though, leave it exactly how it is. I am using ArcGis 10.1 and SDE is still 9.3.1 - works fine. Replicas are created in the current version of the ArcGis desktop that creates them, but must also be reconciled in the same (or better) version. **If you have any concerns contact Esri support to get a definitive answer**

Comment: Yeah, this is the type of question I would ask directly on the ESRI forums. You might try here: https://geonet.esri.com/community/gis/managing-data They have staff that should be able to answer. If you find an answer, come back and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow will not technically be supported, so yes it is dangerous.

Consider this documentation:

Replication and geodatabase releases (10.2.x)
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000z3000000

> Geodatabases built using previous versions of ArcGIS do not support
>   some of the newer functions of ArcGIS. Consequently, if your
>   organization has geodatabases at different releases, consider the
>   following when creating replicas:
>
> For all replication types, **the child replica geodatabase must be the
>   same geodatabase release as or a later release** than the parent
>   replica geodatabase.
>
> Caution: If you upgrade the parent replica's geodatabase, you also
>   must upgrade the child replica's geodatabase before synchronizing.

There are additional scenarios described in that document that are also relevant to your 10.0/10.2 situation.

The risks are pretty high even with simple data, and will almost surely result in errors and potential corruption if you are replicating complex datasets such as topologies, geometric networks, etc. You can potentially corrupt the child geodatabase after only one synch operation.

Depending on your replica type (which is not specified in the question - One-Way versus Two-way, synch direction, full or simple data model, etc.), you may not see any immediate issues. I still do not recommend your workflow.

If you're going to try it anyway, back everything up and run the synch operation manually a few times and trace the results and verify your changes are migrating. Automating an unsupported workflow can break a lot of things very quickly..

The client-release = geodatabase-release relationship that Michael Miles-Stimson refers to is a great recommendation for performing edits and synchronization so long as you stay within the supported replica scenarios outlined in that doc.

Comment: Hi ORA-55378, thanks for the details. I have also checked through the esri link, and we are considering to synchronize the sde version.